# Need sample of registering a gzip/deflate filter in grizzly http server

Tags: grizzly

I would like to see an example of registering a filter in grizzly http server for a specific url mapping (e.g. "/foo") that can handle gzip/deflate compressed payloads.

I am currently registering several HttpHandler instances to handle my different mappings, via something like this

server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(..., myContextPath)

Some of those mappings also need to support gzip/deflate compression. It is not clear to me how that could be done. Sample code or a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Compression within Grizzly is based on response mime-types

You can enable compression on a per-HTTP-Network-Listener basis.

```
server.getListener("grizzly");
```

**grizzly** is the default listener name, you can access it using whatever name you've specified, or you can get all listeners via **getListeners()**.

You can then call **getCompressionConfig()** on the listener instance which returns a **[CompressionConfig](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/CompressionConfig.html)** instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. However, this does not satisfy the requirements. As I stated, SOME of the URI mappings need compression support, while others do not. Is there a way to accomplish that?